# List Of - Insert only if GUID doesn't exist

Tags: vb.net, list

Before I add an item to my List (Of clsUser), I check if no clsUser with the same GUID exists in my list.

Currently I check for the existance like this:

```
Public Function GUIDExists(ByRef uList As List (Of clsUser), ByVal uGUID As String) As Boolean

    For Each nItem As clsUser In uList
        If nItem.GUID = uGUID Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

I would very much like simplify it and add this check to the List (Of clsUser) so that I don't have to write the same code over and over again.

Some like MyList.AddIfGUIDDoesntExists(nNewUser)

Is this possible?
If yes, could anybody tell me how this would be done?

Comment: List(Of T) has a Contains() method built in.

Comment: uList doesn't need to be ByRef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices    

Public Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension()> 
    Public Sub AddIfGUIDDoesntExists(ByRef inputList As List(Of clsUser), _
             ByVal item As clsUser)
        Dim contains As Boolean = False
        For Each i As clsUser In inputList
            If (i.GUID = item.GUID) Then
                 contains = True
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not contains
            inputList.Add(item)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Usage:

```
MyList.AddIfGUIDDoesntExists(nNewUser)
```